# typescript gulp task error

Tags: typescript, gulp, workflow

I'm trying to add typescript task in *gulpfile.js*

**previously** I was using the command `npm run tsc` to compile typescript which is configured in *tsconfig.js*:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  }
}
```

**Now** I want to compile typescripts from a gulp task. in *gulpfile.js:*

```
var gulp    = require( 'gulp' );
var plugins = require( 'gulp-load-plugins' )();
var tsfiles = 'src/app/**/*.ts';

gulp.task('compile', function(){
   return gulp.src(tsfiles)
      // .pipe(plugins.sourcemaps.init()) 
      .pipe(plugins.typescript({
          noImplicitAny: true,
          out: 'output.js'
      }))
      // .pipe(plugins.sourcemaps.write('src/app/maps', {includeContent:false, sourceRoot:'/app'}))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('src/app/')); 
});
```

However, I'm getting 4 errors

```js
[18:20:16] Starting 'typescriptIt'...
src\app\app.ts(1,1): error TS1148: Cannot compile modules unless the '--module' flag is provided.
src\app\app.ts(1,36): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular2/angular2'.
src\app\app.ts(2,1): error TS1205: Decorators are only available when targeting ECMAScript 5 and higher.
src\app\app.ts(6,7): error TS1219: Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Specify '--experimentalDecorators' to remove this warning.
[18:20:18] TypeScript: 4 semantic errors
[18:20:18] TypeScript: emit succeeded (with errors)
```

if you have a better implementation for a typescript task, please share it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out, the solution is easy, I just imported the *tsconfig.json* and all errors are gone

```js
var tsProject = plugins.typescript.createProject('src/tsconfig.json');
gulp.task('compilets', function(){
   return gulp.src(tsfiles)
       // .pipe(plugins.sourcemaps.init()) 
        .pipe(plugins.typescript(tsProject))
       // .pipe(plugins.sourcemaps.write('src/app/maps', {includeContent:false, sourceRoot:'/app'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.app))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the Typescript definition files in your `typescriptFiles`.

`var typeScriptFiles = [
    'folder/**/*.ts',
    'typings/tsd.d.ts //the tsd.d.ts references all the definitions installed
];`

**Installing Typescript Definitions**

`npm install -g tsd`

`tsd init`

`tsd install angular --save`

This will create a `typings` directory which will have your `typescript definition folders and files` and a `tsd.d.ts` file which references all of them.  This file will be required when transpiling from `typescript` to `javascript`.

Hope this help.  Good Luck.

Comment: Neat! I've been getting TS2304 errors in angular files. Your solution resolved this.

Answer (score 0):

I've not seen plugins loaded that way before but the gulp packages will definitely be accessible if you include them at the top of your gulpfile.js.

```
var typescript = require("gulp-typescript");
```

Comment: sorry I just updated my question, `gulp-typescript` is accessible like this using `gulp-load-plugins`

Answer (score 0):

I am compiling my TypeScript using [gulp-tsc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-tsc).

In my gulpfile:

```
var typescript = require('gulp-tsc');

// all typescript files
var typeScriptFiles = [
    'folder/**/*.ts'];

// set the tasks to run
gulp.task('dev', ['compile-ts', 'tsc-watch']);


// watch all TypeScript files
gulp.task('tsc-watch', function() {
    watch(typeScriptFiles, function(file) {
        gulp.start('compile-ts');
    });
});

// compile TypeScript files into folder/ts.gen.js
gulp.task('compile-ts', function(){
  gulp.src(typeScriptFiles)
    .pipe(typescript({out: 'ts.gen.js', emitError: false}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('folder/'));
});
```

Running `gulp dev` will watch the specified TypeScript files and compile them upon change.